# Not showing data of loggid in user while using flask login

Tags: python, flask

I created a login page with flask support for my python script

Here is my python part

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    """Login Form"""
    
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    else:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        if not (username and password):
             flash("Username or Password cannot be empty.")
             return redirect(url_for('login'))
        else:
            try:
                data = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).first()
                if data is not None:
                    session['logged_in'] = True
                    return redirect(url_for('home'))
                else:
                   flash("Invalid username or password.")
                   return redirect(url_for("login"))
            except Exception as e:
                flash("Error")
                return redirect(url_for("login"))
```

within my template I try to get the information which is provided in the data variable but i cannot acces to it.

here is my template part

```
{% if session['logged_in'] %}
                                                {% if data %}
                                                <h3 color="black">{{data}}</h3>
                                                {% else %}
                                                <a href="/logout">Logout</a> <br> <br>
                                                {% endif %}
                                                {% else %}
                                                <li id="navi02"><a href="/login">Login</a></li>
                                                {% endif %}
```

the part " {% if session['logged_in'] %}" is running fine but the second partis not working. What is wrong?

Regards

Comment: I don't see you returning data anywhere. If you are returning it somewhere else , please paste that code too here.

Comment: No I don't return it so what is wrong?

Comment: You need to return it to use it in html.rather redirecting to home `return render_template("your_home.html",data=data)`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you pass values in templates:

```
return redirect(url_for("login", data=data, loggedin=session['loggedin']))
```

or

```
render_template("login.html", data=data, loggedin=session['loggedin'])
```